# How to add multiple subscribers at a time in a list using campaigning (0.15.0) gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-plugins

Now i have added subscribers one at a time to a list.

How to add multiple subscribers at a time to list in campaign monitor.

I am using campaigning (0.15.0) gem in **ruby on rails application**. rails version i**s 2.3.4**.

In campaign monitor documentation here [http://www.campaignmonitor.com/api/subscribers/#importing_subscribers][1]

Any one pls give me answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Campaigning gem have the functionality to import single subscriber at a time. And use the gem CreateSend. By this gem you can access the v3 api of campaign monitor so that we can import mulitiple subscriber at a time.